# How can I save the code in chrome console tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log, page-refresh, inspect-element

On the console tab on chrome I pasted this code into it and every time I refreshed the page it got rid of what I added in. Is there a way where I could save the code even when I refresh the page?

If my grammar doesn't make sense let me know.(Its like 3AM in the morning right now)

Comment: your page? add it to your code. Someone elses page ... there's some monkey themed addons you can use to do that

Comment: You are looking for user scripts runner, for example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pl